# Vuejs Unit test can't mount properly

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js

I am struggling to properly run test on my components.
So I have something like:

```html
<Tabs class="tabsComponent" @tab-selected="tabSelected">
    <Tab icon="Icon" >
        <AnotherForm/>
    </Tab>
    <Tab icon="Icon">
        <ReturnForm/>
    </Tab>
</Tabs>
```

Then in tabs I am getting children Tab component, and also with that I dynamically import icon from another place

```js
this.tabs.forEach(tab => {
    if (tab.icon) {
        try {
            // dynamic icon import
            this.$options.components[tab.icon] = () => import('@/components/global/assets/' + tab.icon);
        } catch (err) {
            tab.icon = null;
        }
    }
});
```

I am getting errors that `icon` is not defined, not sure in which place as line points to css so I am guessing that's not valid line.
Therefore my tabs are not mounted, I struggle to troubleshoot that.
In my test I use `mount(Tabs)` so it should mount all child components?

so in that Tabs I want to be able to click one with but I am not finding any functional components

Test here:

```js
import Tabs from '@/components/Tabs';
import { shallowMount,mount } from '@vue/test-utils';

describe('Tabs Present And Clickable', () => {
    it('Check Tabscomponent', async () => {
        const wrapper = mount(Tabs);
        const tabReturn = wrapper.find('#tab_1');
        await tabReturn.trigger('click');
        expect(wrapper.find('#tab_1').exists()).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Comment: Include your test spec in the question.

Comment: I have added it to the post